# assigning strings a number based on its column in a data frame

Tags: r, performance, indexing, dataframe

I have somewhat of a beginner question. It is related to efficiency and using less lines of code. (I plan on majoring in computer science in college and i figured getting better at coding would be good!) I have a data set with 45 variables and 1000+ observations, but I need to manipulate 3 of the variables and find the lowest value in each of these columns.

For example, I have variable 1 (call it "var1") in column 11, variable 2 ("var2") in column 17, and variable 3 ("var3") in column 23. I have a function that takes a string as an argument (var1, var2, or var3), goes into that column in the data set, and loops through it and searches for the lowest value.

Currently my code seems pretty inefficient:

```
whichLowest <- function(variable) {
# Function has some read.csv things and other pre-computational stuff here
  if (variable == "var1")
     varData <- subset(myDataset, select = colnames(stateData)[11])
  else if (variable == "var2")
     varData <- subset(myDataset, select = colnames(stateData)[17])
  else if (variable == "var3")
     varData <- subset(myDataset, select = colnames(stateData)[23])
  else
     stop("invalid outcome")
for (i in varData) {
# calculates lowest value in that column
}
```

As you can see, I have 3 if statements inside the for loop to find out what the variable that is given to the function. Because I have 3 if-statements, I feel like there is a more efficient way to do this. My thought is something like assigning var1, var2, and var3 some number and then doing the same thing. However I don't know how to approach this!

Comment: Please post a reproducible example (code to generate your data, possibly using random)

Comment: Using a string to lookup a column is called ***column indexing (by name)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to look up the dataframe column by (string) variable name, then take the `min` or `which.min` of that column (and you don't need a for-loop: `min` and `which.min` are vectorized, like most R functions):

```
set.seed(103)
df = data.frame(var1 = sample(1:20, 10), var2 = sample(1:20, 10), var3 = sample(1:20, 10))

#   var1 var2 var3
#     5   10    4
#     2    6   11
#    10   15   10
#     9   18   18
#    19   17    9
#    16    2   14
#     7   16   15
#     3    4   13
#     1    5    5
#     4   13   17

min(df[,'var2'])
# 2

yourvar = 'var1'
min(df[,yourvar])
# 1

yourvar = 'var2'
min(df[,yourvar])
# 2

yourvar = 'var3'
min(df[,yourvar])
# 4
```

If you want to reference it by column-index, use `apply` like Matt O'Brien shows.

Comment: ...and who's this MikeOBrien guy? ;)

Comment: ``yourvar= 'var2'` is just some made-up variable, to illustrate the point that we can use a string as a column-index in a df. Sorry I got your name wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad there's a min function as well. Makes life easier.

Comment: Right. You should never need to write a for-loop to execute a function on a vector. Most functions in R are vectorized, and for the few that aren't, use sapply/apply. Never a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
df <- data.frame(Var1=c(1,2,3), Var2=c(2,3,4), Var11=c(9,10,11))

apply(df, 2, min)
#Var1  Var2 Var11 
#   1     2     9
```